# Automatically add GRANT EXECUTE to Drop&Create script in MSSQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a context menu in MSSQL - Script Stored Procedure as -> DROP and CREATE

But when I am generating procedure, it do not contain existing GRANT EXECUTE role. 
How can I add (automatically!) it to generating script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SSMS, go to Tools, Options, SQL Server Object Explorer, Scripting and in the Object Scripting Options section, change Script Permissions to True.

Comment: maybe you know how remove "AS [dbo]" after GRANT EXECUTE * TO* ?